# JavaScript array.sort does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting

I'm using the built-in sort() method on an array of objects in JavaScript by providing a compare function which I think meets the needed requirements, as it returns 1, -1 or 0 whether item A compares bigger, smaller or equal to item B, respectively.

This is the code:

```
aData.sort(function(itemA, itemB) {
    if (itemA.field1 > itemB.field1) return 1;
    if (itemA.field1 < itemB.field1) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

This works perfectly in Iceweasel/Firefox (Version 38.6.1) on a Debian 8 VM but it's completely useless when using Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit)).
No sorting whatsoever is done, the array is left completely unchanged!

I've upgraded Chrome, spent several hours searching for solutions for this problem so far but no avail.

Any ideas, guys?

Much obliged!

Comment: What exactly is happening in chrome? Error? No change to the list? Incorrect reordering?

Comment: please add some example data for sorting

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5mpa587w/

Comment: Without an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes input test values this can't be reproduced

Comment: I've edited the post, in Chrome nothing happens, the array is left unchanged.

Comment: I found out what the real issue was. What I was trying to sort was actually an associative array (ie an object) instead of a pure array. Anyway all other browsers handle it, so it's kind of a drag that Chrome is so picky about it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar problem, maybe it is the same situation.

I guess that your data come from a backend that is returning the fields as strings instead of Ints

```
[{"field1":"222"},....]
```

instead of

```
[{"field1":222},....]
```

I've never pinpointed why but, the framework that was being used on the application seemed to convert the values to Int on Firefox but not on Chrome.

The solution was to use parseInt on the function that defined the ordering.